# How to prevent of removing last zero when convert a matrix to a string in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, converters

I want to convert a matrix to a string and because of some reasons don't want to delete last zero from my string.

I have a matrix like;

```
a=[38.30 64.90 90.50];
```

If you type a on command window will shows:

```
38.3000   64.9000   90.5000
```

It's OK but when I want to convert it to string like:

```
x=num2str(a(1,1));
```

result is: "38.3", How can I have this result "38.30"?

I test it like num2str(a(1,1),4) but it doesn't work.

Comment: The reason why `num2str(a(1,1), 4)` doesn't work is that the optional input `4` specifies a _maximum_ number of precision digits (try `num2str(pi, 4)`), but zeros are still trimmed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional second argument for `num2str` can be a formatStr like that for `sprintf`, so you can do

```
num2str(a(1,1), '%.2f')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [38.30 64.90 90.50];
x = sprintf("%.2f ", a);
```